# HTaccess Redirect is adding query to end of URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've got another redirect I'm having some issues on.

While it DOES redirect, once the page loads, the rule somehow adds everything after the question mark at the end of the URL.

So, badexample.com would show up as badexample.com/?p=1297

Here's the rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} ^/wordpress/\?p=1297$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.badexample.com [R=301,L]
```

Any ideas on this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want a query to appear after a rewritten URL, in theory you could use the `[QSD]` flag (Query String Delete I think it stands for).  In practice however it sometimes doesn't work too well in my experience.

Instead, add an empty query string to your new url:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.badexample.com? [R=301,L]
```

This will stop any additional query string being added.